# Django model ordering issue

Tags: python, django

This is my model:

```
class Feature(models.Model):
    name         = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True)
    order        = models.SmallIntegerField()
    group        = models.ForeignKey(FeatureGroup)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']
```

The "Features" are being correctly display in the admin control panel based on the value specified in "order".

I have this in my view:

```
p = get_object_or_404(Phone.objects.prefetch_related('brand', 'features__feature', 'photo_set'), id=id)
```

I templates I have `{% for feature in phone.features.all %}... {{ feature.feature }} ...`

The values are being displayed correctly but in random order.

What's wrong and how can I overcome this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: in your view, you seem to assign `p` to a single object, retrieving it  by `id`.  A single element will have no sort order, or you need to order by the `id`s you are using to retrieve with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the template filter `dictsort`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#dictsort

`{% for feature in phone.features.all|dictsort:"order" %}`